Linux Wifi Issues after Update on May 19, 2024
I am using a TP Link 3U plus which was working prior to the update.
arundeep@arundeep:~$ uname -srm
Linux 6.5.0-35-generic x86_64
arundeep@arundeep:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Installed using:
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
cd rtl88x2bu
sudo make uninstall
sudo make

What I have tried
arundeep@arundeep:~$ ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.76  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2001:569:527e:2000:8ac8:fd43:57e7:822f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:569:527e:2000:abd:e8fc:e046:39a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::a3e2:7d8b:a464:3270  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:59:eb:42:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5894  bytes 5617696 (5.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2677  bytes 790602 (790.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 784  bytes 69974 (69.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 784  bytes 69974 (69.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

arundeep@arundeep:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1038:1622 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Apex 3 TKL
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1038:1824 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Rival 3
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 26ce:01a2 ASRock LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

arundeep@arundeep:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for arundeep: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: a8:a1:59:eb:42:89
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-28-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.76 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
arundeep@arundeep:~$ nmcli general status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 
arundeep@arundeep:~$ nmcli radio  wifi 
enabled
arundeep@arundeep:~$ nmcli connection show --active
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  c7027acb-a5a6-3903-a4ef-98322cc582a5  ethernet  enp4s0 

While loading 88xbu.ko
arundeep@arundeep:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo insmod 88x2bu.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 88x2bu.ko: Unknown symbol in module

arundeep@arundeep:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dmesg

[   34.656424] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   34.880612] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.175799] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.469719] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   35.687476] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.980754] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   36.088450] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[   36.547631] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   36.574684] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   36.808830] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.010748] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[   37.204512] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   37.231567] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.461845] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.663477] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   37.665851] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[  989.376961] 88x2bu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  989.376981] 88x2bu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  989.377050] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -2)
[  989.377069] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel (err -2)
[  989.377097] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -2)
[  989.377119] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err -2)
[  989.377143] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err -2)
[  989.377162] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -2)
[  989.377186] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -2)
[  989.377194] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data (err -2)
[  989.377216] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -2)
[  989.377227] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -2)
[  989.377236] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -2)
[  989.377251] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -2)
[  989.377266] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -2)
[  989.377280] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status_ext (err -2)
[  989.377296] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -2)
[  989.377306] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -2)
[  989.377342] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -2)
[  989.377352] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_ext (err -2)
[  989.377364] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -2)
[  989.377383] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -2)
[  989.377405] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb (err -2)
[  989.377416] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -2)
[  989.377435] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_external_auth_request (err -2)
[  989.377445] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -2)
[  989.377486] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -2)
[  989.377494] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -2)
[  989.377515] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -2)
[  989.377539] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_started_notify (err -2)
[  989.377554] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -2)

Tried fixing that part
arundeep@arundeep:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo modprobe cfg80211
arundeep@arundeep:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo insmod 88x2bu.ko
arundeep@arundeep:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dmesg
[   34.656424] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   34.880612] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.175799] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.469719] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   35.687476] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   35.980754] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   36.088450] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[   36.547631] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   36.574684] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   36.808830] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.010748] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[   37.204512] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   37.231567] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.461845] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[   37.663477] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   37.665851] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[  989.376961] 88x2bu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  989.376981] 88x2bu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  989.377050] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -2)
[  989.377069] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel (err -2)
[  989.377097] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -2)
[  989.377119] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err -2)
[  989.377143] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err -2)
[  989.377162] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -2)
[  989.377186] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -2)
[  989.377194] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data (err -2)
[  989.377216] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -2)
[  989.377227] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -2)
[  989.377236] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -2)
[  989.377251] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -2)
[  989.377266] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -2)
[  989.377280] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status_ext (err -2)
[  989.377296] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -2)
[  989.377306] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -2)
[  989.377342] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -2)
[  989.377352] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_ext (err -2)
[  989.377364] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -2)
[  989.377383] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -2)
[  989.377405] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb (err -2)
[  989.377416] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -2)
[  989.377435] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_external_auth_request (err -2)
[  989.377445] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -2)
[  989.377486] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -2)
[  989.377494] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -2)
[  989.377515] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -2)
[  989.377539] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_started_notify (err -2)
[  989.377554] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -2)
[ 1308.582176] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[ 1308.582379] Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[ 1308.582517] Loaded X.509 cert 'wens: 61c038651aabdcf94bd0ac7ff06c7248db18c600'
[ 1320.662039] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu

I tried unpluging all my cables to reset but nothing. All other usbs but the usb wifi adapter and all ones after that one don't work.
Fixing that error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin/32194268#32194268
arundeep@arundeep:~$ dpkg -S sign-file
linux-headers-5.15.0-107: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-107/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/scripts/.sign-file.cmd
linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic/scripts/.sign-file.cmd
linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-21: /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-21/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-107-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-35: /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-35/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-18: /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-18/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic/scripts/sign-file
linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-28: /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-28/scripts/sign-file.c
python3-gpg: /usr/share/doc/python3-gpg/examples/howto/sign-file.py
python3-gpg: /usr/share/doc/python3-gpg/examples/howto/encrypt-sign-file.py
python3-gpg: /usr/share/doc/python3-gpg/examples/howto/detach-sign-file.py
python3-gpg: /usr/share/doc/python3-gpg/examples/howto/clear-sign-file.py
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-46: /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-46/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-39: /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-39/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic/scripts/sign-file.c
linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/scripts/sign-file.c

sudo apt install hashalot
[sudo] password for arundeep: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  cryptsetup
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hashalot
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 52.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 hashalot amd64 0.3-10 [15.4 kB]
Fetched 15.4 kB in 0s (65.3 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package hashalot.
(Reading database ... 368743 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hashalot_0.3-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hashalot (0.3-10) ...
Setting up hashalot (0.3-10) ...
arundeep@arundeep:~$ /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/scripts/sign-file sha512 ./signing_key.priv ./signing_key.x509 /rtl88x2bu/88x2bu.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: /rtl88x2bu/88x2bu.ko
arundeep@arundeep:~$ /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/scripts/sign-file sha512 ./signing_key.priv ./signing_key.x509 /rtl88x2bu/88x2bu.ko
At main.c:298:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
sign-file: /rtl88x2bu/88x2bu.ko

https://superuser.com/questions/1214116/no-openssl-sign-file-signing-key-pem-leads-to-error-while-loading-kernel-modules/1322832#1322832
arundeep@arundeep:~$ echo -e "[ req ] \n\
default_bits = 4096 \n\
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name \n\
prompt = no \n\
x509_extensions = myexts \n\

[ req_distinguished_name ] \n\
CN = Modules \n\
\n\
[ myexts ] \n\
basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE \n\
keyUsage=digitalSignature \n\
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash \n\
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid" > x509.genkey
arundeep@arundeep:~$ openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -sha512 -days 36500 -batch -x509 -config x509.genkey -outform DER -out signing_key.x509 -keyout signing_key.pem



arundeep@arundeep:~$ sudo mv signing_key.pem signing_key.x509 `find /usr/src/*-generic/certs`
mv: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/certs/certs' with '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/certs'
mv: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/certs/certs' with '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic/certs'
mv: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/certs/certs' with '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic/certs'
mv: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/certs/certs' with '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic/certs'
mv: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/certs/certs' with '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic/certs'

Updated:
arundeep@arundeep:~$  dpkg -l |grep iwl
arundeep@arundeep:~$ dkms status
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-101-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-102-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-78-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-82-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-84-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-86-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-87-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-91-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-94-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 6.5.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 6.5.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1, 6.5.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-101-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-102-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-78-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-82-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-84-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-86-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-87-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-91-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-94-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 6.5.0-28-generic, x86_64: built
rtl88x2bu/git, 6.5.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
arundeep@arundeep:~$ sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1 -k 6.5.0-28-generic
[sudo] password for arundeep: 
Module rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1 for kernel 6.5.0-28-generic (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

88x2bu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....
Deleting module rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
arundeep@arundeep:~$ dkms status
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-101-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-102-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-78-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-82-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-84-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-86-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-87-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-91-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-94-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 5.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 6.5.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.2.2, 6.5.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-101-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-102-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-78-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-82-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-84-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-86-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-87-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-88-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-91-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-94-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 6.5.0-28-generic, x86_64: built
rtl88x2bu/git, 6.5.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed


Which update? A Ubuntu update? If so you'll have to recompile against the new kernel, if the Ubuntu update installed a new kernel (also I guess you mean May 19, 2024)

So you cloned the repo, ran sudo make + insmod and no dice? Sorry but it's not clear if by "installed using [...]" you mean that you originally installed the driver like that or if you did that after the last update

Orginally did that. Than I did sudo make uninstall inside that and did sudo make again and then did insmod. Where I got new errors. uname -r
6.5.0-35-generic

Did you clone the repo again or did you use the same files you cloned the last time? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, basic triaging...

Should be the same files. Just noting where I got it from. Looks more like a power issue or something from connecting the usb wifi adapter.

I'd freshly clone the repo and try again. Otherwise you may try and compile an older version (there are links to some archived versions in the github page)

Also tried that as well didn't work as well. I did a timeshift as well before update and it also didn't work.

Ah I just noticed the message: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194268/4316166 (or actually this, which should be the proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983070/4316166)

If those answers don't help please add all the information you gave me about what you did to the question, so that we can remove the comments and so that someone else can chime in.

Tried a bunch of things and updated so far.

Put it on the top.

Results for dkms status; dpkg -l |grep iwl

Updated with those results

You may want to remove all the dkms installs, delete the files in /usr/src/ that are related to them and remove the links in /var/lib/dkms if they still exist.  Then try cloning the source code and install them again using dkms.  The issue involves the source code and has nothing to do with module signing
